# wcf rest service not working in wp8

Tags: wcf-rest, windows-phone-8-emulator

While trying to consume rest service in windows phone 8 app , I am getting the "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."exception.

All that am trying to do is creating a simple WCF rest service and trying to consume it in a WP8 application. I have tried all the possible solutions mentioned in several articles digging this problem but couldn't escape this exception. I have even tried this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

but no enough lucky. I have also disabled firewall.

One important thing to mention here is am connected to a corporate network, does this affect in any way?

Answer (score 0):

yes it does.
Windows Phone 8 Emulator has a separate IP of its own, different from the IP of the host computer. It needs an internet connection which is shared with the internet of the host system.
If the host system is in a corporate network, this means, most probably, you are having a restricted internet policy.
For running the REST service on the emulator, you need to have an unrestricted internet connection in the emulator.